# Eclipse clean has removed most of my import statements

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was getting "The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files" errors in all of my projects after a reboot (I run Eclipse on Windows 7). Everything was working fine before the reboot. So I tried cleaning all projects and restarting Eclipse - a few times. That didn't work so I followed some advice here and shifted 
rt.jar up the list in my Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs. That seemed to fix the problem for all of the appcompat_v7* projects, but....

Now I find that Eclipse has rather helpfully removed most of the import statements from all of my classes. This leaves me with about 1,000 compilation errors to deal with. Is there a quick way of re-instating the required import statements, or do I really have to go to each class, each error and manually re-instate each import??

Comment: "The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files" -- go to Project > Properties from the main menu, choose the Android category, and click on your desired build target. Right now, my guess is that you have none of those build targets.

Comment: You're saying "Project->Clean" edited files. That shouldn't be. That shouldn't be at all.

Comment: You really need source control like git for example. I wouldn't be that bothered if I lost imports, as it would take me minute or two to get back.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click button on the project and select Source>Organize Imports.

That should work... if you have the libraries set up correctly.

Comment: +1 That's very cool. I didn't realize "Organize Imports" could also work for an entire project at once.

Comment: Thanks. That's taken care of most of the problems. It found 55 that it couldn't deal with - class "contains ambiguous references. User interaction required" - all referring to the ActionBar object ????

Comment: Yes, that happens when you have a class that is contained in several packages and Eclipse needs your help to define which is the package you want. It is a pain, but if you go class by class you have to do the same thing.

Comment: Every time this sort of thing happens I start exploring alternative IDE's that are more stable/reliable than Eclipse, but it seems that there is nothing out there that completely fits the bill :0(